# Error: cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to move a row from one table to another.

The problem is that if I put both queries together, I get "error: cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement". What can I do?

```
exports.deletePost = function(id) {
    return db.query(`INSERT INTO deletedjobs
    SELECT *
    FROM jobs
    WHERE id = $1;

    DELETE FROM jobs WHERE id = $1;`, [id]).then(results => {
        console.log("succesfull transfer");
        return results.rows[0];
    });
};
```

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: Following [Docs](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#multi) v7.0.0, I found out `db.multi` can execute a multi-query string, you can try this:

```
db.multi(`INSERT INTO deletedjobs
    SELECT *
    FROM jobs
    WHERE id = $1;DELETE FROM jobs WHERE id = $1`, [id])
```

---

Other way I think the better solution is that you should wrap the query into a function for insert-delete at same time, like below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION moveJob(id character varying) RETURNs void AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO deletedjobs
    SELECT *
    FROM jobs
    WHERE id = id;

    DELETE FROM jobs WHERE id = id;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER
  COST 100;
```

And call it as postgresql function in your js:

```js
db.any('select moveJob($1)', [id]);
```

Comment: Thanks ThnhPhan. I just tried your updated solution but I got "db.multi is not a function"

Comment: I also tried running the function in my terminal psql, but I got "ERROR: function result type must be specified" :/

Comment: I have already updated return in function, can you try it again

Comment: Thanks Thanh, now I created the function, unfortunately I get db.multi / db.any is not a function because I am using this [spicedPg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/spiced-pg) npm instead of pg-promise.

Comment: My answers is based on [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), it's popular to connect to PostgreSQL, you should use it

Comment: Thanks, I'll check into it

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a `WITH ... AS` clause (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-with.html) to execute both queries in one go. So it could look something like that:

```
exports.deletePost = function(id) {
return db.query(`
  WITH 
    A AS (SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE id = $1), 
    B AS (INSERT INTO deletedjobs FROM A),
    DELETE FROM jobs WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM A);
`, [id]).then(results => {
    console.log("succesfull transfer");
    return results.rows[0];
});
};
```

Answer (score -2):

- Maybe you should not use `AND` clause, try semicolon `;`.
- You used `select    *` you should enter columns name, because in later
  times you may add a new column, your function does not execute.

Comment: but when I use semicolon is that I get this error "error: cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement"

Comment: 1) You can't "And" an insert and delete.
2) If he's just after a flat record copy, how is this a problem?